# Iterate(ng-repeat) angular array objects with start and end

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm looking for an option to give start and end  while looping the array of object in angular.

Now i'm using ng-repeat.

My use case is like i have a section "top" were 3 items to be  shown from "lists"(array of objects) sorted by date

and in another section "more" rest of the items have to be shown that is 4 to lists.length.

and i want to use same "lists" as sources rather than pushing to two different array.

As there is an option to delete items from both sections, deleting item from "top" section should pull items from "more" section to "top".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use angular's limitTo filter in your ng-repeat.

```
ng-repeat="item in items|limitTo:3"
```

Here is a startWith filter to help also:

```
app.filter('startWith', [function() {
    return function(input, index) {
        return input.slice(parseInt(index, 10));
    };
}]);
```

Use it like this:

```
ng-repeat="item in items|startWith:4"
```

Comment: Thanks it works like a charm, i added input.length in filter and  used 3  instead of 4